# How to add event in background in google calendar?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to add event in `Google Calendar`. Flow is as follow.

First i select any one date from my custom calendar, and then on `OnDateClickListener` I save the event directly to the `Google Calendar` in background just add the text like "completed" so how is it possible?

Please help any demo any source code or any suggestion. How can i start with that?